# Bitcoin fake transactions

Tags: transaction-verification

Suppose, A and B are malicious attackers. Both want to send unlimited fake transactions to each other. I know that the transactions won't be accepted in the blockchain. In fact, they don't want their transactions to be mined. But, is there any way to take a countermeasure against A and B? And, what will be the cost?

Answer (score 2):

The countermeasure is built in the system. All non malicious nodes would instantly discard the fake transactions.
I don't understand the problem statement though, like why would any one want to broadcast fake transactions without any motive that it gets mined.

Comment: I think OP is trying to imagine some kind of denial of service attack.

Comment: and soon enough the fake node will be blacklisted by many other nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Either the transactions are valid (including offer a sufficient fee) or not. If they are fully valid, then they will get mined and A and B will pay lots of fees. If they are not fully valid, then everybody will ignore them and they will do no harm whatsoever.